# Concerns with dynamically calling stored procedures inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a need to have a single stored procedure that will dynamically call one of over hundreds of stored procedures.  Our concern is that this may cause issues with the plan cache and suffer from parameter sniffing.

We are looking at calling the second stored procedure using sp_executesql.

Has anyone else done this?  Any ways to mitigate issues we may run into?

Comment: Have you tested any of this yet to warrant your concerns?... might not have any issues at all, but won't know until you test.

Answer (score 3):

Each stored proc, both the outer and each inner, will have its own plan in the cache.

If the outer procedure does nothing but construct dynamic SQL then call sp_executesql its plan will not be sensitive to the arguments passed. If it does complex lookups to construct the dynamic SQL then you may have issues.

Each inner proc will have its own plan too, independent of the outer proc's plan. If the inner SP would be sensitive to sniffing when called directly it will have the same sensitivity when called dynamically. Your proposed approach will neither cause nor fix this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do use `sp_executesql` here.

The second (inner) stored procedure will get its own cached plan, which can be used for any parameters for that procedure. But the plan for any other inner procedures will be cached separately.

While this can cause plan cache bloat, you probably *want* this, as it means that each individual query can use the best query plan, while at the same time allowing proper parameterization. There would only be one plan per procedure, not per set of parameters.

I see no reason to use `sp_executesql` at all in this instance. Assuming all the inner procedures have the same set of parameters, you can actually pass `EXEC` a variable as the name of the procedure to execute.

For example:

```
DECLARE @proc nvarchar(257) = (SELECT ProcToCall FROM SomeTable);

EXEC @proc
  @someParam = 1;
```

This means that you will not get any plan caching issues due to `sp_executesql` itself and building dynamic `EXEC` strings. Although `EXEC` itself is *not* normally cached, other commands such as `SELECT` may get cached.